# ASP.NET Core Web Application console closes immediately

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET Core Web Application using its console profile. The console opens and closes immediately so I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in browser. Is it possible to find out why the console/host closes? There is nothing in event log and I've enabled stdout but it doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Without a code example of your Program.cs and Startup.cs I don't think anyone can help.

Comment: how are you exactly running the project? Post some code maybe

Comment: It's a default Empty Web Project with nothing in it. It fails to start when I update all of the .NET components to the latest versions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to start you app from already open console window.

Run `cmd`, navigate to your project folder and execute `dotnet run`.

Your app will start and terminate, but console window will remain open and you will see exception (if any) or other output that may help you.

Comment: The app does not terminate, unless you yourself stop it

Comment: App in question do (_"console closes immediately"_) - possibly some exception is thrown from Startup class.

Comment: Oh my bad I missunderstood what you meant, you are right :)

Comment: Thanks, it was a version problem with Microsoft.NETCore.App component.

Comment: My issue was I didn't have the correct dotnet version installed in my computer